# implementing apt in MobileSafari

Tags: objective-c, ios, mobile-safari, apt

Does anyone know how to use APT on a website, so respringing, installing/uninstalling .debs, etc work like Cydia, but just on a web browser?

Comment: You want to build a browser based package manager, you mean?

Comment: pretty much, i guess you can say that

Comment: You should define exactly what you want to do, and then try build it.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really any App Store like package manager for the web. There is Webmin though, which has a built-in package manager frontend to apt.

https://doxfer.webmin.com/Webmin/Software_Packages

Edit: look into https://github.com/linuxappstore/linuxappstore as it might be what you are looking for.